# Package restoration in AEM CQ5

Tags: aem

Is there any way a deleted package can be restored or a history of package installation can be seen in AEM CQ5?
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah its possible in AEM author instance . In your CRX lite navigate to crx/packmgr/index.jsp .Clicking On (more-->older versions ) will show you the different versions history used for that particular package so far and you can also restore the package to the version that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can view older versions of packages installed from the CRX Package Manager. Once you find the package you are after, click the "More" button and you can view Older Version from there.

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/crx/2-3/how_to/package_manager.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check all the installed packages and restore is from the directory **/etc/packages/{group-name-of-the-package}/**